# is there a way to setup this rule in outlook to identify emails just to me (no other to or cc)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

is there a way to setup a rule to isolate emails that are sent directly to me and noone else is cced or in the to:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create a rule for arriving emails where the condition is "sent only to me".